# stylus style formatting in vue files with VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, stylus

I have a vue file composed as followed (not really important) :

```
<template>
    //some pseudo-html
</template>

<script>
    //some javascript
</script>

<style lang='stylus'>
  @import '~variables'
  .card
    cursor pointer
    //some more stylus
</style>
```

I have `formatOnSave` activated in VSCode, I also have vetur and esLint installed.

When I use CSS code inside a classic `<style>` tag, I have no problem, but when I use `lang='stylus'`, ESLint is still looking for CSS ( I get syntax errors like `[css] { expected (css-lcurlyexpected)` ).

Also, the auto-format on save just mess eveything up when I use stylus, it puts everything on the same line. Result after save :

```
<style lang='stylus'>
  @import '~variables'
  .card cursor pointer position relative padding //some more stylus
</style>
```

I tried to change the followinf settings in vscode :

`vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css`
`vetur.format.defaultFormatter.stylus`

but to no avail.

My current settings:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "FlatUI Immersed",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 2,
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.fontSize": 15,
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "markdown.extension.preview.autoShowPreviewToSide": true,
  "markdown.preview.breaks": true,
}
```

And workspace specific settings :

```
"settings": {
    "files.associations": {
      "*.vue": "html"
    },
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    // Defines space handling before function argument parentheses. Requires TypeScript >= 2.1.5.
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
    // Defines space handling before function argument parentheses. Requires TypeScript >= 2.1.5.
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
    // Eslint options
    "eslint.enable": true,
    "eslint.options": {
      "extensions": [
        ".html",
        ".js",
        ".vue",
        ".jsx"
      ]
    },
    // An array of language ids which should be validated by ESLint
    "eslint.validate": [
      "javascript",
      "javascriptreact",
      {
        "language": "html",
        "autoFix": true
      }
    ],
    // Run the linter on save (onSave) or on type (onType)
    "eslint.run": "onSave",
    // Turns auto fix on save on or off.
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  }
```

It would be absolutely awesome if someone knows how to have the formatter and the linter correctly take that into account, but after 2 hours digging, i would honestly settle for **a way to disable the formatter and the linter just for the `<style>` tag.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after digging some more, i found a solution :

delete this part of the settings :

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.vue": "html"
 },
```

And replace `html` by `vue` in this part :

```
"eslint.validate": [
   "javascript",
   "javascriptreact",
   {
     "language": "vue",
     "autoFix": true
   }
 ],
```

And also add :

```
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "none"
```